# Amazon S3/Cloudfront Image Overwriting Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently serving up static images to my site via Amazon Cloudfront and for some reason my images won't update when I try to overwrite them with an updated image. The old image continues to display.

I've even tried deleting the entire images folder and uploading the newest ones without success. The only thing that works is renaming the image.

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 3):

recently amazon s3 announced new feature called content invalidation. it allows you to invalidate some file just with a one call. check cloudfront api references for more details.